# How to create dc.js series chart with multiple factors

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to create a series chart in dc.js using time series data.  I would like to segment the series chart by both the attribute and person column.   The plot should show 4 lines corresponding to 'attr_1' and 'attr_2' for each person 'ALL' and 'JANE, DOE'.

If I sum over the attribute, I get the plot to work using the following code.  My question is, how do I modify this code to produce the plot that I describe above?

Data:

```
 year_month |     person    |    attribute      |         value         
------------+-----------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------------
 2015-07-01 | ALL           | attr_1            | 16867.083333333333
 2015-07-01 | ALL           | attr_2            | 11488.583333333333
 2015-07-01 | JANE, DOE     | attr_1            | 23533
 2015-07-01 | JANE, DOE     | attr_2            | 16151
 2015-08-01 | ALL           | attr_1            | 16467.000000000000
 2015-08-01 | ALL           | attr_2            | 10557.458333333333
 2015-08-01 | JANE, DOE     | attr_1            | 23454
 2015-08-01 | JANE, DOE     | attr_2            | 14379
 2015-09-01 | ALL           | attr_1            | 16225.800000000000
 2015-09-01 | ALL           | attr_2            | 13024.080000000000
 2015-09-01 | JANE, DOE     | attr_1            | 23935
 2015-09-01 | JANE, DOE     | attr_2            | 19612
```

Code which lives in $.ajax function call:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(data);
var chart1 = dc.seriesChart("#chart1");
var ndx = crossfilter(data),
xDimension   = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return [+Date.parse(d.year_month), d.person, d.attribute];}),
yGroup       = xDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.value;});

function series_chart(chart) {
    chart
    .width(400)
    .height(300)
    .chart(function(c) { return dc.lineChart(c).interpolate('basis'); })
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([new Date("7/01/2015"), new Date("6/01/2016")]))
    .brushOn(false)
    .yAxisLabel("Dummy Label")
    .xAxisLabel("Month")
    .seriesAccessor(function(d) {return "person: " + d.key[1];})
    .keyAccessor(function(d) {return +d.key[0];})
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {return +d.value[0];})
    .dimension(xDimension)
    .group(yGroup);
    return chart;
}

series_chart(chart1)
.brushOn(true);

chart1.renderlet(function (chart) {
        // rotate x-axis labels
        chart.selectAll('g.x text')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(-10,10) rotate(315)');
    });

dc.renderAll();
```

Comment: Looks like you have a syntax error in your dimension definition. Could you put together a working (or not working) example? Here is a JSFiddle that should have the necessary libraries loaded: https://jsfiddle.net/esjewett/jusjkm8j/

Comment: You are correct, there was a misplaced square bracket on that line.  I edited the post to correct.

Comment: I added the code to the fiddle you linked jsfiddle.net/esjewett/jusjkm8j.  It seems like I would need to modify either the seriesAccessor or keyAccessor but I do not know exactly what I would change.

Comment: You'll need to fork the JSFiddle and save it with a new URL for me to be able to see your changes.

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/7xpjkfv7/

Comment: Maybe another way to phrase my question is: how do I build a seriesChart for data structures that contain multiple keys?

Comment: No time to put together a real answer, but here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/esjewett/o6krg7fz/